# How can I configure WinSCP so that connection error windows don't steal the focus?

Tags: windows, winscp

How can I configure WinSCP so that connection error windows don't steal the focus?

Example of connection error window that  stole the focus:

[image]

I use WinSCP 5.7.6 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: What focus? Do you have another application activated and WinSCP steals a focus, when the error occurs?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have another application activated and WinSCP steals a focus, when the error occurs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Actually applications cannot steal focus in Windows (at least not in versions of Windows from the last decade or two, definitely not in Windows 7).